# Wordpress Pagination on static homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to get Pagination working on my static homepage which I have integrated with wordpress. The problem I am having is when I click the "Older Entries" button on the page it goes to the ?paged=2 page but displays the first 10 posts still. Just like on the first page.

I know the code somewhat works because I changed `($the_query->max_num_pages > 1)` to 2 and went to the page and it displayed the contents of the second page with a "Newer Entries" button.

I just cannot get it to do it automatically.

I used this persons tutorial on how to set it up 
http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination

and here is my code

```html
<?php
  // set up or arguments for our custom query
  $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
  $query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged
  );
  // create a new instance of WP_Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); // run the loop ?>
  <article>
    <h1><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
  </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
  <nav class="prev-next-posts">
    <div class="prev-posts-link">
      <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
    </div>
    <div class="next-posts-link">
      <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); // display newer posts link ?>
    </div>
  </nav>
<?php } ?>

<?php else: ?>
  <article>
    <h1>Sorry...</h1>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
  </article>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The website (temporary) can be seen here http://auroraservers.org/MainSite/Index.php

So you can see what it is doing.

Thank you for any help! I've been trying to fix this for over a day now so I hope it isn't too much trouble.

Comment: Welcome to SO, 3253191. Please try to use only relevant tags for your questions. I came on your question from the `CSS` questions stack and it has nothing to do with `CSS`.

Comment: Oh sorry I've just been working on stuff all day and put some out off the top of my head of what I was recently working on. Won't happen again! I promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line should be `paged` instead of `page`

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Comment: Older versions of WP indeed used `page` as `query_var`. For a while we actually had to check both and get whichever was populated, if any. Apparently, he has hit an outdated tutorial. Good spotting!

Comment: Oh thank you for that little bit of information and the answer to my problem! I'm really trying my best to understand how things like this work as I'm trying to get work in the industry as a Junior Web Developer :)